# I am trying to implement ECDSA signature verification algorithm. I am facing errors in the synthesis part

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, vivado, synthesis

I wrote a synthesizable Verilog HDL code in Xilinx Vivado to implement ECDSA Signature Verification. There are no syntax errors, but synthesis failed. The inputs I am taking are of 7 bits each - r,s,P,Q. I have left out the hashing part(instead I explicitly tried declaring the 32 bit hashed value e, where e = H(m), m being the message of 32 bits.). Still there are errors while synthesis. I have listed out the errors after the code. There are no output bits from this module, so will the Vivado truncate the code? If yes, how should I resolve it?

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module signature_verification(r,s,P,Q);
parameter n = 80;//n is declared to be 80
integer i;
input wire [6:0]r;
input wire [6:0]s;
input wire [6:0]P;
input wire [6:0]Q;
reg e[31:0];

//creating array of elements 1 to n-1
integer verify_array[0:78];
initial
begin
    for(i=0 ;i<79;i = i+1)
        verify_array[i] = i+1;
end
//check whether r and s integers fall in the array of elements 1 to n-1
initial
begin
    for(i=0;i<=80;i = i+1)
        begin
        if(r[i]!=verify_array[i])//recheck
            begin
            if(s[i]!=verify_array[i])
                $display("Reject the signature.");
            end
        end
end


//e = H(m) left out
//for the time being skipping the hashing part
e <= 32'b10000000000111000000000001111111

//finding modular inverse of s
function [6:0]w;
input [6:0]s;
input [6:0]p;
integer i;
begin
    for(i=1;i<p;i=i+1)
        begin
        if(((s%80)*(i%80))%80 == 1)
            begin
            w[i] = i;
            end
        end
end
endfunction

//------------------------------------------
//computing u1 and u2
reg [6:0]u1; 
initial
begin
for(i=0;i<7;i=i+1)
begin
u1[i] <= ((e[i]*w[i])%n);
end
end

reg [6:0]u2; 
initial
begin
    for(i=0;i<7;i=i+1)
    begin
    u2[i] <= ((r[i]*w[i])%n);
    end
end


reg [6:0]X;
reg [6:0]X_int;
initial
begin
    for(i=0;i<7;i=i+1)
    begin
    X[i] <= ((u1[i]*P[i])+(u2[i]*Q[i]));
    end
end

//converting X to v
reg [6:0]v; 
initial
begin
    for(i=0;i<7;i=i+1)
    begin
    X_int[i] = int(X[i]);
    v[i] <= (X_int[i]%n);
    end
end

//checking if v=r
initial
begin
    for(i=0;i<=80;i = i+1)
    begin
    if(r[i]!=X_int[i])//recheck
        begin
        if(r[i]!=X_int[i])
            $display("Reject the signature.");
        end
    end
end
endmodule
```

Here I have to check whether X is approaching Infinity. How can I do that in Verilog HDL, since it is a hardware description language unbounded elements cannot be checked?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your questions correctly. Please try to be more specific about the question and post the errors. However, I will try my best to answer as much as I understand. Point to be noted, I am also a newbie to vivado/FPGA development. Dear experts, Please be kind enough to correct me if my answers seem wrong to you.

1. The good practice for Verilog to be **"synthesized"** is to use an output port to my knowledge. Let's say done=1 when signature generation is done. My best guess is if there is no output port, vivado shouldn't give you an output for "synthesis". Imagine you are trying to build a circuit that takes input but doesn't generate any output. I believe vivado optimization will not find a solution to generate a synthesizable circuit. To my understanding and knowledge, the circuit doesn't make sense at all. There might be special cases where this might be applicable, which I haven't seen so far anywhere tbh.
2. For unbounded elements, my best guess would be to use a large enough number as a reference of infinity which will indicate that X is approaching infinity. You can also switch to the system Verilog. I believe there might be instances where you can use unbounded checking.